# How to create foreign key that is also a primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, inheritance, foreign-keys, primary-key

This should be a fairly straightforward question, but I'm unable to find an easy answer.  How do you create a foreign key that is also a primary key in MySQL?  Here's my current attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE Sale(
    sale_id CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(sale_id),
    discount DOUBLE,
    type VARCHAR(255),
    price DOUBLE,
    );

CREATE TABLE Normal_Sale(
    sale_id CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(sale_id);
);

CREATE TABLE Special_Sale(
    sale_id CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(sale_id);
);
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This design doesn't look right. To me it seems like you could just add a field to Sale which marks it as Normal or Special. This smells

Comment: You are *over-normalizing* the schema. As Joe Phillips says, a much simpler solution exists. Your design could lead to headaches as the two states should be mutually exclusive (either normal, or special), what prevents a sale to be recorded as both special and normal in your schema? *Code*, you say? That's it; that's the headache you don't need.

Comment: These are just dummy examples. The question is not a design question, it is a technical one.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Add `FOREIGN KEY (sale_id) REFERENCES Sale(sale_id)` to each foreign table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sale(
    sale_id CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(sale_id),
    discount DOUBLE,
    type VARCHAR(255),
    price DOUBLE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Normal_Sale(
    sale_id CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(sale_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (sale_id) REFERENCES Sale(sale_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Special_Sale(
    sale_id CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(sale_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (sale_id) REFERENCES Sale(sale_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Just make sure your database is `InnoDB` which supports Foreign References.

Comment: Thank you for seeing this as a technical question. Jut the answer I needed.