# MySQL FK Error 1005 - same PK as FK

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a ques similar to:
[How to create foreign key that is also a primary key in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575051/how-to-create-foreign-key-that-is-also-a-primary-key-in-mysql?newreg=b911ac2a0cb246218b9e0dc076f7c137)

however my schema seems to match the answer but still returns the error "ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table (errno:150)"

```
CREATE TABLE po_items (
job_id          CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
po_id           CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
item_id     CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
quantity        SMALLINT,
PRIMARY KEY (job_id, po_id, item_id),
FOREIGN KEY (job_id, po_id) REFERENCES pos(job_id, po_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE items (
item_id         CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
descr       CHAR(10),
on_hand         SMALLINT,
price           DECIMAL(5,2),
PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES po_items(item_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a `foreign key`, the referenced field must have indexed.

As per documentation on `foreign key` constraints:

> REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)

Define an `INDEX` on `item_id` in table `po_items` and it should be working.

```
CREATE TABLE po_items (
job_id          CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
po_id           CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
item_id     CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
quantity        SMALLINT,
KEY (item_id),
PRIMARY KEY (job_id, po_id, item_id),
FOREIGN KEY (job_id, po_id) REFERENCES pos(job_id, po_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>       [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>       REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>       [ON DELETE reference_option]
>       [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>       RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION

Comment: thanks so much Ravinder - I didn't get the 'reference the relation' in the earlier question, this has made it clearer for me