# How do I create another table from an existing table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable, mysql-workbench

I have a table called UserInfo like this:

```
Userid     Job     Age
John       A       35
Sarah      B       27
```

and I want to create another table like this called UserScores (score is null):

```
Userid     Score
John       
Sarah
```

Where the userid column is the same exact as the other table. How would I do this with SQL? This is what I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE UserScores AS
    SELECT userid, score
    FROM user
```

Here's my error message:
[image]

I need the userid to be the primary key in my UserScores table as well. How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: user has no scores so how should mysqlm know where the score come from and for the primary alter the table

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575051/how-to-create-foreign-key-that-is-also-a-primary-key-in-mysql

Comment: @nbk, ah well i was planning to leave the scores empty, my bad let me fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add NULL as value to scores as below and add  the promary kley after creatuing the table userscores

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (userid INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user VALUES (1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE UserScores AS
>     SELECT userid, NULL AS score
>     FROM user
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE UserScores
> ADD PRIMARY KEY (userid);
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b785ced2ff32731afa467f928e125e1f)*

**EDIt**

you should also define the type of score in the create

```
CREATE TABLE UserScores (userid  int, scrore int) AS
    SELECT userid, NULL AS score
    FROM user
```

Comment: note that you will likely want to change score's data type after this.  I'd just make the table the way you want, keys and all, and then `insert into UserScores (userid) select userid from user;`